# How do I get an ID then edit the data in the datatables

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables

I have data from the API, I can bring up the data in view with datatables, but I'm confused to edit from ID based,

this my controller

```
 $response = Curl::to('127.0.0.1/post/show')->get();
        $data = json_decode($response, true);    
        $outputData = $data["data"];

        return Datatables::of($outputData)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row-id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>';
                $btn = $btn . ' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>';
                return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
```

f i use $ row-> id it will show an error trying to get property of 'id' of non-object

this my script datatable

```
$('#tAdmin').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ordering: false,
               ajax: "{{route('postshow')}}",
               columns : [
                    {"data" : "id"},
                    {"data" : "author_id"},
                    {"data" : "articel"},
                    {"data" : "action"}

               ]
          });
```

this is when dd($outputData)

```
data": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "author": "james",
     "artikel" : "some artikel",
    "action" : "a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\"  data-id=\"\" data-original-title=\"Edit\" class=\"edit btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-edit\"><i class=\"far fa-edit\"></i></a> <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\"  data-id=\"\" data-original-title=\"Delete\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete\"><i class=\"far fa-trash-alt\"></i></a>"
      "vendor_id": "1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to Use this to overcome your problem

```
   $row['id']
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202779/discussion-between-albus-severus-and-vandy).

Answer (score 1):

Just change in your code

`data-id="'.$row['id'].'`

```
 $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row['id'].'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>';
 $btn = $btn . ' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>';
```

Comment: @misry Please don't feel pressured to accept _any_ answer. It's completely up to you if, when and which answer you accept.